# How to load one of many external JS arrays and reference the variable in specific external JS file

Tags: javascript, arrays

I apologise in advance if this question is repeated elsewhere. I am at a loss as to how to correctly phrase the question to find the answer through research alone.

I have many external js files which each contain a js array. I can reference these files and pull them into my webpage easily enough, but accessing the array via a placeholder isn't working. If the file is named 'walberton.js' the array it contains is named 'walberton'.

myBoundary = 'walberton'

The following works as the placeholder for the array is implicitly stated (walbertonx):

```
function showHideBoundary(myBoundary) {
    var boundarySourceFile = myBoundary + '.js'; 
    if (typeof walbertonx == 'undefined') {
        var poll;
        var timeout = 100; // 10 seconds timeout
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.src = boundarySourceFile;
        document.body.appendChild(s);
        poll = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
        timeout--;
        if (typeof walbertonx !== 'undefined') {
            // External file loaded
            drawWSCountyBoundary(walbertonx);
        } else if (timeout > 0) {
        poll();
        } else {
        // External library failed to load
        alert("Apologies. Unable to load Boundary at this time.");
        }
        }, 100);
    };
    poll();
    } else if (walbertonx !== undefined && line === undefined && line.getMap() === null) {
        drawWSCountyBoundary(walbertonx);
    } else if (walbertonx !== undefined && line !== undefined && line.getMap() !== null) {
        line.setMap(null);
    } else {
        line.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

The idea is code-reuse for all 163 boundary files I have. So, in the same way as I can reference the file with myBoundary, I can replace walbertonx with the actual variable once it has successfully loaded. The trick is I need to know what to check for before it's loaded and once it's loaded use that rather than the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Code in the global scope should be accessible to all files loaded after it. Ensure that you include your 'walberton.js' file first. Afterwards you should be able to access the array granted it's in the global scope.

You could also attach the array to the window object if that suits your fancy, like so:

```
Window.walberton = walberton
```

Then you can access it in your secondary file like this

```
alert(Window.walberton)
```

If it is that you want to dynamically add them, consider having a global object array on the window

```
Window.fileArrays['walberton'] = walberton
Window.fileArrays['other'] = other
```

You'd ensure you do this in each file where you want to add an array.
Then you can iterate over them. Just ensure you detach them from the window when you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems I need to do further research to correctly deduce the wisdom you seek to impart. Will this somehow bypass the has it/has it not loaded yet issue I face when loading in large files before acting on them?

Comment: @mackaszechno yes. HTML, CSS, and JS files are all loaded sequentially as included. Therefore if you put one js file before the other in the html document, that js file will always always load before the next. If you're still having issues you should update your question with more info / pictures and other details.